# Can I travel and live in Ireland with refugee document from Malta?

Tags: ireland, refugees, malta

My family and I were given refugee status in Malta. Can I work and live with my family in Ireland using those refugee status documents?

Comment: Why have you tagged your question 'canadian citizens'? Are you a Canadian refugee in Ireland (seems unlikely)? Have 'the same right' as who/what?

Comment: Which country issued the refugee status document?

Comment: It was issued to me and my family in Malta

Comment: @brhans, I guess the OP didn't find a relevant tag, and, since one tag is mandatory, chose arbitrarily.

Comment: @ugoren - [Ireland](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ireland), [Refugees](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refugees) - didn't really try very hard did they?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you received refugee status in Malta and now you want to emigrate to Ireland without additional visa or residence permits? The answer is **"no."**

You can *apply for permission* to emigrate to Ireland. Such questions are best asked on [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com) stack exchange.